# airflow - clean up database before backfill task

Tags: python, airflow

I need to clean up databases (postgres/mongo) before backfilling of tasks connected to aiflow DAG. Let's assume this simple DAG:

```
     ->task2
task1       ->task4
     ->task3
```

Each task writes it's results to database

**On normal execution** on daily basis everything is ok - there is no data in databases regarding processing actual day.

**But when it comes to backfill** of this DAG, when past days were already processed but we need backfill to compute results one more time (i.e. code for task2 was changed and we need refresh) there are already data in databases to corresponding past days and there will be i.e duplicateError raised during backfill. So now I need to delete manually data corresponding to tasks that need backfill before executing backfill.

**I want to**: for each task make script which will do cleaning corresponding data from databases for current execution date and run this script **just before** running real task that will fill data in databases once again. But for performance reasons I want this **deletion script** to run only when there is backfill processed and not run it on daily execution of DAG.

**What I am missing** is how to tell if task is being run by backfill or normal daily execution (some flag etc) or maybe there is option to run something like `pre_task_execute_when_backfill_callable` function to assign somewhere in airflow task?

Answer (score 0):

For now I have ended with two methods like below:

```
def is_task_backfill(day: datetime.date) -> bool:
    """check if task is running on new day data or 
    is it running in backfill mode"""
    return day < datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)

def delete_day_data_when_backfill(day, session, func, **kwargs):
    """clean up data from postgres/mongo table that corresponds with day parameter.
    Main purpose is to run this method before backfill
    
    :param day: date for deletion of corresponding data for current task
    :type day: datetime.date 
    """
    if is_task_backfill(day):
        func(day, session, **kwargs)
```

I'm calling `delete_day_data_when_backfill()` on the start of each task that I would like to execute with corresponding function that cleans databases as parameter. So DAG task module could look like this:

```
def delete_day_data(Table, day, session):
        session.query(
            Table,
        ).filter(
            Table.date == day,
        ).delete()

def fill_database_with_day_data(day):
   with Session(engine) as session:
      delete_day_data_when_backfill(day, session, delete_day_data)
      function_that_fills_with_day_data()
```

Sum up:
**I was missing** the way to tell whether **airflow is executing as backfill** or **airflow is executing normal daily task**. So the **answer to question is this method:**

```
def is_task_backfill(day: datetime.date) -> bool:
    """check if task is running on new day data or 
    is it running in backfill mode"""
    return day < datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)
```

if execution `day` is less than `.today() - timedelta(1)` it will be backfill executing in my situation (when task are executed on daily basis). Very simple condition and I haven't found any flag in documentation of airflow, but I wasn't search for long.

Hopefully that helps somebody :)